# How can I enter Unicode bold Fraktur math characters with LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode

I want to write a paper with Old/Biblical-Hebrew (Tiro) and Old-Greek words in it. Now I have made my first experience with LuaTeX and it worked well. But I also want to use this symbol http://codepoints.net/U+1D578 - and I totally fail. Which way would you recommend? Only type it into the editor doesn't work. There is no error, but in the PDF is an empty space and no "MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL M". I need exactly this one, because it stands for an old source.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Ezra SIL}
\newcommand{\textheb}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\hebfont #1\egroup}

\begin{document}

   which is U+1D578 MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL M

some Hebrew: \textheb{ יִשְׁאַג }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try using the math symbol between $ signs (ie in math mode). Otherwise you need to define a fallback font for Times New Roman that has the math glyph (I don't know how to define fallback fonts in latex)

Comment: if you want to use this in its mathematical context just use that character and include a suitable math font (eg stix). If you want a bold _text_ fractur just use a normal `M` and choose a bold fraktur font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a font that has the glyph, for instance STIX. For just a few characters, the simplest way is to use `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\stix[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX}

\newunicodechar{}{{\stix}}

\begin{document}

   which is U+1D578 MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL M

\end{document}
```

I removed the Hebrew part, which is irrelevant.

[image]

Comment: I had to change "STIX" in "STIXGeneral" - but then it works perfectly - thanks a lot!

Comment: @nomis In the last release, the font is called STIX